# Why compiler is not issuing error while passing an int (not int *) as the argument of scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

I tried the below c program & I expected to get compile time error, but why compiler isn't giving any error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() 
{
  int a,b;
  printf("Enter a : ");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("Enter b : ");
  scanf("%d",b);
  printf("a is %d and b is %d\n",a,b);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

I am not writing `&` in `scanf("%d",b)`. At the compile time ,  compiler don't give any error but during execution value of b is 2686792(garbage value).

Comment: Do you compile with `-Wall` or any specific warnings activated?

Comment: Why should it not compile? `scanf` and `printf` familes are variadic functions which receive unknown types, so the compiler can't check if the type of the parameters are correct or not. All parameters of them follow default promotion

Comment: There's no reason it should fail at compile time.

Comment: However, smart compilers know how to parse the format string (the first argument) of `printf()` and `scanf()` families of functions and issue warnings.

Comment: There is no compile time error.

Comment: @uditr043 , But there might be a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per `C11` standard, Chapter §6.3.2.3

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

So, the compiler will *allow* this, but the result is implementation-defined.

In this particular case, you're passing `b` to `scanf()` as an argument, which is *uninitialized*, which will cause the program to invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), once executed.

Also, `printf()` / `scanf()`  being variadic functions, no check on paramater *type* is perforfmed in general, unless asked explicitly through compiler flag [See `-Wformat`].

Answer (score 1):

It is not a a compile time error but a runtime issue.

The compiler expects that you have given a valid address to scan the value to, during runtime only it will come to know whether the address is valid or not .

If you try to scan the value to invalid address it leads to undefined behavior and might see a crash.

Answer (score 1):

It scans fine because `scanf` expects a memory location in its argument. That's why we use `&` to give memory location of the corresponding variable.

In your case `scanf` just scans the entered value and puts it in the memory location which has the value of `b`(instead of scanning and putting it in the memory location where `b` is stored).

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator in C returns the address of the operand. If you give just the b without the `&` operator, it will be passed by value and the `scanf` won't be able to set the value. This would result in unexpected behaviour as you already noticed. It has no way of verifying the address before the runtime and hence you won't notice the issue until runtime.